# FFMPEG Creating multiple outputs in windows with concat

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I would like to convert a video in different filesizes with ffmpeg.
On Debian the following code works fine

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/clients/client1/web46/cdn/latenight/latenight-22-Sep-18-21:09:01.flv -i /var/www/clients/client1/web46/cdn/latenight/latenight-22-Sep-18-21:09:01.flv \ -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -threads 1 -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60  -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -ar 48000 -b:a 320k /var/www/clients/client1/web46/cdn/latenight/test_high.mp4 \ -preset ultrafast -strict -2 -threads 1 -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -vf scale=640:360 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k /var/www/clients/client1/web46/cdn/latenight/test_low.mp4;
```

While in windows batch with concat:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt -i D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt \ -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 320k D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_high.mp4 \ -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -vf scale=640:360 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_low.mp4
```

It is giving me out the error "Unable to find a suitable output format for '\'
: Invalid argument"

Comment: Your problem might stem from the `-=` in your paths. Wrap the paths in quotes and see if that works.

Comment: I tried it sadly the error message is the same  "Unable to find a suitable output format for '\' \: Invalid argument"

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked closer. In: `D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_high.mp4 \ -y`, note the space after `mp4` and just before `\`.

Comment: If you had posted with the quotes, I probably would have spotted that on the first pass.

Comment: I added quotes, but can't remove the space, if i do so it is resulting in "Unable to find a suitable output format for '\-y'" The current code is now (but again with the same error)
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt" -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt" \ -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 320k "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_high.mp4" \ -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -vf scale=640:360 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_low.mp4"`

Comment: In bash, a backslash and newline is a line continuation. Seems you have 2 of these so the command may have been 3 lines. Line continuation in batch-file is caret `^` and newline. Suggest replacing both backslashs with caret and a newline.

Comment: That did it :) can you please answer it so i can give you probs! It was the form that you suggestet, thanks  `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt" -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt" ^
-y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 320k "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_high.mp4" ^
-y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -vf scale=640:360 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_low.mp4"`did work

Comment: Do not put that much code in a comment. The formatting is difficult to read. Edit your question with any updates you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt"^
 -i "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\convertme\index.txt"^
 -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -movflags +faststart^
 -c:a ac3 -b:a 320k "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_high.mp4"^
 -y -preset slow -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -r 60 -vf scale=640:360^
 -movflags +faststart -c:a ac3 -b:a 128k^
 "D:\-=streaming=-\concats\x265-website_low.mp4"
```

In bash, a backslash and newline is a line continuation.

Line continuation in batch-file is caret `^` and newline.

The 2 `\` are removed from the command.
The quite long command line is continued across many lines
using `^` and newlines to make it more compact to view.

Paths have been double quoted for visual clarity.